# Filter data with date that is stored as string instead of DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i have two fields in a which will input start date and end date, so i want to filter the data according to the dates entered and display only data in those date ranges, my database the date field is stored as a string not DateTime so iam struggling with writing the query in Linq to filter the data. so far i search i check if the two fields are not null then i'm struggling with query

```
 if (search.StartDate == null && search.EndDate == null)
            if (search.StartDate!= null && search.EndDate != null)
            {
                    var startDate = search.StartDate;
                    var endDate = search.EndDate;

                    query = query.Where(d => (d.Date) >= startDate.Date && (d.Date) <= endDate.Date).AsQuerybable();
            }
```

Comment: What format are your dates stored in the strings?

Comment: Why you have to store them as strings? How much work it would be to fix this mess instead of working around?

Comment: I guess you regret storing the date as a string. it will come back to bite you 1000 times. just fix the glaring error and be done with it

Comment: i inherited this project from someone, so the person that created the database didnt do it properly he stored everything as nchar

Comment: Why is this `(d.Date)` in brackets? Are your dates stored as YYYYMMDD, YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY/MM/DD or DD/MM/YYYY, DD-MM-YYYY, MM-DD-YYYY, etc, etc ??? It makes a difference to whether your query will make sense. Do your search date formats match the database formats?

Comment: the date is stored in the format MM.DD.YYYY, and i put them in brackets when i hadnt realised that the DB date is stored as string because i was using DbFunctions to trim the time when querying

Comment: That's unfortunate

Comment: i'm good now thanks for the assistance everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your dates are stored MM.DD.YYYY you will have an issue writing these queries as in a string comparison:

```
12.03.1964 > 04.06.2017
```

So Ideally your would need to change the date formats throughout your DB to either a Date, or at least to a YYYY-MM-DD format so that a meaningful range can be applied server side.

The second best solution would be to create a view or stored procedure in your database to return records from the table applying a range on the dates so that the range can be applied server side.

The solution that requires no change to your database can only apply the date range client side and involves getting the individual parts of the string together in the correct order:

```
query = query.Where(d => 
    DateInRangeFormat(d.Date) >= DateInRangeFormat(startDate.Date)
    && DateInRangeFormat(d.Date) <= DateInRangeFormat(endDate.Date))
    .AsQuerybable();

// accepts date in MM.DD.YYYY format and returns YYYYMMDD
public static string DateInRangeFormat(string date)
{
    return date.SubString(6) + date.SubString(0, 2) + date.SubString(3, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, i have changed the whole DB because i was gonna have to write a lot of queries for other functions so that was gonna be a problem